# ReCaptcha within a Selenium browser

Tags: python, selenium, captcha, recaptcha

I am currently writing a script to automate the process of navigating through a handful of pages and fill a form; however, before the final form can be submitted a google ReCaptcha needs to be solved by the user. When my script reaches this point I have it stop so that I can complete the ReCaptcha and submit the form manually. Now this is where I am having issues. When I attempt to solve the ReCaptcha I always get an error that says 'Please Try Again' or something like that (Yes I am 100% sure I am solving them perfectly). While investigating this issue I also tried the audio option that ReCaptcha offers. This option does not even allow me to hear the audio, instead it says "We're sorry, but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now."

So, my question is: How do I prevent getting this error message when I am trying to solve the captcha manually? Do I need to add a delay to my script?

I am very confused and I do not know how to fix. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: You have to talk with the developer to turn the recaptcha off while you are testing it! there is not any other way to automate your script while using recaptcha.

Answer (score 0):

Performing manual operation while running automation scripts is not recommended.

Possible solution is please ask your dev team for a workaround, like configure CAPTCHA in test environment in such a way it will always accept 1 specific value.
or
ask to disable the CAPTCHA in testing environment.

Hope this [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17022/how-to-fill-captcha-using-test-automation) useful.